# Multidimensional array in a object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run following code:

```
var groupSocketIdList={};
var groupId=5;
if (groupSocketIdList[groupId] == undefined) {
  groupSocketIdList[groupId] = [[]];
}
groupSocketIdList[groupId]["tolgay"] = "1234";
var sendData = {
  groupPassCode: groupSocketIdList[groupId]
}

console.log(sendData.groupPassCode[groupId]);
```

It is returning `undefined` but when I try like this:

```
console.log(groupSocketIdList[groupId]);
```

It works well.

How can I prevent from `undefined` ?

Comment: `sendData.groupSocketIdList[groupId]` has neither `groupSocketIdList` nor the array for an index call `[groupId]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `groupSocketIdList[groupId]` should be Object
2. `groupSocketIdList[groupId]` should be just reference to `groupSocketIdList`

```js
var groupSocketIdList = {};
var groupId = 5;

if (groupSocketIdList[groupId] == undefined) {
    groupSocketIdList[groupId] = {};
}

groupSocketIdList[groupId]["tolgay"] = "1234";

var sendData = {
  groupPassCode: groupSocketIdList
}

console.log(sendData.groupPassCode[groupId]);
console.log(sendData.groupPassCode[groupId]['tolgay']);
```

Comment: Is there a way to use like this?

var sendData = {
  groupPassCode: groupSocketIdList[groupId]
}

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
groupSocketIdList[groupId] = [[]]
```

to

```
groupSocketIdList[groupId] = {}
```

`(groupSocketIdList[groupId]["tolgay"] )` this means you are defining a `property` for `groupSocketIdList[groupId]` it should be an object but you defined it as a array so thats why you are getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Last step

```
console.log(sendData.groupPassCode[groupId]);
```

to

```
console.log(sendData.groupPassCode);
```

You will get all data Of List

Answer (score -2):

You should call like this.

```
console.log(sendData.groupPassCode['tolgay']);
```

Because your object is in this format:

```
{
    'sendData': {
        'groupPassCode' : [[]]
    }
}
```

your adding property to array not to object.